# How to update schema without one object in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update my schema without one object.

When i updated my schema the req.body automaticly updating schema with $set.
But i want to prevent update all schema.
For example req.body can include user role and this case i don't want to update user role.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
 { _id: req.user._id },
 { $set: req.body },
 { new: true, runValidators: true },
)
```

So i want to update all body without role object in user schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to do that you can so this

```
User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id },(err,user)=>{
       if(err) throw err; 
       user.FieldYouWantToUpdate = req.body.name // likewise add your values

       // then save the document
       user.save();
     });
```

In here you can have more control to yourself when doing an update using mongoose.
What heppens is you query using a user id and get a user. so that user object can be accessed within the callback of the findOne() function. 
After that using the user object you can alter the user as you want may it be a single field, 2 fields, all fields what ever you like. You can have the full control over update

Comment: if you are happy with the answer, please vote and mark the answer mate :)

Comment: Thanks for answer, Actulay i can update like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295766/update-part-of-mongoose-schema but i don't know which object will came with body or schema object can be 20-30 and i don't want to update one by one. Is not there a method like select ('-discard') ? And also i have no rep for vote :) next time.